# Docker request to own server

Tags: node.js, apache, http, docker, express

I have a docker instance running apache on port 80 and node.js+express running on port 3000. I need to make an AJAX request from the apache-served website to the node server running on port 3000.

I don't know what is the appropiate url to use. I tried localhost but that resolved to the localhost of the client browsing the webpage (also the end user) instead of the localhost of the docker image.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This depends… the "api url" should be configurable, for dev environment this should be "localhost", but in production it should rather be the domain name. Without knowing your exact setup (how do you manage different environments, which environment are you talking about) it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First you should split your containers - it is a good practice for `Docker` to have one container per one process.

Then you will need some tool for orchestration of these containers. You can start with `docker-compose` as IMO the simplest one.

It will launch all your containers and manage their network settings for you by default.

So, imaging you have following `docker-compose.yml` file for launching your apps:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    image: apache

  node:
    image: node # or whatever
```

With such simple configuration you will have host names in your network `apache` and `node`. So from inside you node application, you will see apache as `apache` host.

Just launch it with `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 1):

> make an AJAX request from the [...] website to the node server

The JavaScript, HTML, and CSS that Apache serves up is all read and interpreted by the browser, which may or may not be running on the same host as the servers.  Once you're at the browser level, code has no idea that Docker is involved with any of this.

If you can get away with only sending links without hostnames `<img src="/assets/foo.png">` that will always work without any configuration.  Otherwise you need to use the DNS name or IP address of the host, in exactly the same way you would as if you were running the two services directly on the host without Docker.